# MS Access - Advancing through record groups

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I have a form with a subform. The record source for the subform is as follows:

```
SELECT [firstID], [secondID], [AAA], [BBB], [CCC], [DDD] 
FROM   Table1 
WHERE  firstID = [Forms].[frm1].[txtfirstID];
```

The subform groups the records together on the basis of txtfirstID but when I advance through the record selector it goes through every record, as expected. I would like to know if there is a way to click through the groups rather than each record within each group. I'm open to any way of doing it. Perhaps filtering through VBA??

Thanks!

Comment: What is your end goal? To be able to filter the recordset so that you're only looking at all records within a specific group?

Comment: Yes! For example, I have 5 records. Three records have an ID of 5. Two records have an ID of 6. The subform will show the three records of 5 (because txtfirstID = 5) but it only advances one record at a time. So I have to advance 3 times to get to the next group of records with an ID that equals 6. I would like to be able to advance once and get the next **group** of records. Somehow I need to increment the txtfirstID?? I don't know. txtfirstID has number gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a combo box to your form. Set the RecordSource for the combo box to a distinct list of groups, or, if you have a group lookup table, `select * from tblGroups`. Set the display field to be group name, and the value field to be group id.

Second, after an item is selected from the combo box, modify the RecordSource sql of the form (your query) so that it uses the current value of the combo box. The value of the combobox would be what your where clause should be looking for.

Comment: That's great! It took me a while to get it working but it works! I had to do a requery in the after update event of the combobox. Thanks, Lynn!

Comment: Why modify the RecordSource? Why not just Link Master & Link Child?

Comment: @Fionnuala It's a teaching moment; now the OP understands the broader concept of using input from form elements to use as criteria in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do two ways to solve this:

1.- If you related main form to subform by a field. In this case TxtFirstID of Main to FirstID of subform. It do all work when change main form and filter automatically on subform

2.- You can do and event OnChange form TxtFirstID on main form.

```html
Sub TxtFirstID_Change()
Me.subfrmName.Form.RecordSource = "Select * from table1 where firstID=" & Me.TxtFirstID 'change the record source for the SubForm
me.subfrmName.Form.Requery 'Force Access to refresh the Record Source
end sub
```